# TFS - Query Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RootCause from DB, to generate a report using SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, tfs-2015

Query Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RootCause from DB, to generate a report using SSRS

Kindly let me know where I can get the Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RootCause values for Bugs in TFS so that it can be reported using SSRS

I have checked in dbo.CurrentWorkItemView & dbo.DimWorkItem in TFS_Warehouse Database and was not able to find it.

Please assist in finding the values for Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RootCause for Bugs

Answer (score 0):

The [Bug tracking fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/cmmi/guidance-bugs-issues-risks-field-reference-cmmi?view=vsts#bugs) are **neither reported nor indexed**.

By default there isn't the field in Bug WIT. So, to track the **RootCause** field (`Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RootCause`), you need to add the field first. Refer to [Add or modify a field to track work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-field?view=vsts) for details.

You can also customize the bug work item type with the **Process Editor** ([TFS 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power))

Based on my test we can retrieve the values of RootCause field from the table `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCustomLatest]`

[image]

Comment: @Uday S Have you resolved the issue? Is the answer helpful? any update?